# can we Prevent Force update from play console?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I would like to prevent my app from force update. I'm looking up for a solution to manage force update from play console. Do we have any option to do so?

to make it more clear, what I want is to give the users who want the update a way to update the app manually but I don't want the update to be pushed as "Auto update" to all users.

Comment: The user himself can do that.  As the app owner, the easiest way to not force update is just not to post an update at all.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a way:

**Option 1**

- you can roll out the release for 1% only
- in this case only 1% of users will receive auto update
- and any one who want the new update will be able to get it if they went to play store. in this case they will see `update` button and can manually update the app

**Option 2**

- you can release the update a open beta version
- this way only people who want to see the update will do
- they will join beta testing program and receive the update

Comment: I'm not sure for option 1 but it seems to get working. I didn't try it yet. I will let you know if it works.